# Why is BeautifulSoup not fetching title from eBay?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape listings from eBay lising page aka the front page. My code is printing all other required details i.e. URL, shipped from, condition, and price but is not printing the title.

I am scraping the listings and putting them into a CSV file. Even if I print them on the console it says "Title: None"

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

def scrape_rolex_listings(reference_numbers, num_pages=1):
    """Scrape Rolex watches listings from eBay.

    Args:
        reference_numbers: An array of Rolex reference numbers.
        num_pages: Number of pages to scrape (default is 1).

    Returns:
        A list of dictionaries, each of which contains the following information about a Rolex watch listing:
        * Title
        * Price
    """

    listings = []

    for reference_number in reference_numbers:
        for page_number in range(1, num_pages + 1):
            url = f"https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2380057.m570.l1313&_nkw={reference_number}&_sacat=0&_pgn={page_number}"
            page = requests.get(url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

            items = soup.find_all("div", class_="s-item__info")

            for item in items:
                listing = {}



                title = item.find("h3", class_="s-item__title")
               

                print("Title:", title)
                if title is not None:
                   listing["title"] = title.text

                price = item.find("span", class_="s-item__price")
                if price is not None:
                    listing["price"] = price.text

                listings.append(listing)

    return listings

if __name__ == "__main__":
    reference_numbers = ["116233"]
    num_pages = 3  # Number of pages to scrape
    listings = scrape_rolex_listings(reference_numbers, num_pages)

    # Specify the CSV filename
    csv_filename = "rolex712.csv"

    # Write the listings to a CSV file
    with open(csv_filename, "w", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        csv_writer.writerow(["Title", "Price"])

        for listing in listings:
            csv_writer.writerow([listing.get("title", ""),
                                 listing.get("price", "")])

    print(f"Listings saved to {csv_filename}")
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, `find()` didn’t find anything, so it returns `None` - You try to find a `<h3>` but there is only a `<div>` so change your selection for `title` to:

```
title = item.find("div", class_="s-item__title")
```

Answer (score 0):

You´re trying to find an 'h3' tag, that´s why you´re getting "None", instead you should look for a 'span' tag with "role": "heading"
It would be something like this:

```
title = item.find("span", {"role": "heading"}).text
```